# How was the AES MixColumns matrix constructed?

Tags: aes

How was the constant matrix in AES MixColumns constructed?

\begin{bmatrix}
02 & 03 & 01 & 01 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 01 \\
01 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
03 & 01 & 01 & 02 \\
\end{bmatrix}

How can I construct in $GF(2^4)$ an invertible matrix for the MixColumns step?

Comment: how was it constructed? with a circulant matrix containing the smallest possible values to get the job done

Comment: There's an entire book (230 pages) about the design of AES, it's called: "The Design of Rijndael: AES – The Advanced Encryption Standard.", chances are the answer is in there somewhere...

Comment: Read at least the [Rinjdael submission, section 7.3](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf#page=29)

Answer (score 3):

Any full rank $n \times n$ circulant matrix $A$ with all entries nonzero generates an MDS code. The entries here were picked for efficient fast multiplication, as far as I can recall.

Do refer to the book suggested by @SEJPM for more.